# .NET Core 3.1 - EntityFrameworkCore - DBContext.Query obsolete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I find many examples and tutorials where functions are obsolete, but it's hard to find replacements for them

here is an examble, the Query function is obsolete, yet I cannot find what to use in it's place

```
SqlParameter usernameParam = new SqlParameter("@username", usernameVal ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
SqlParameter passwordParam = new SqlParameter("@password", passwordVal ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

string sqlQuery = "EXEC [dbo].[LoginByUsernamePassword] @username, @password";

lst = await context.Query<Authenticate>().FromSql(sqlQuery, usernameParam,passwordParam).ToListAsync();
```

in this case, this line does not compile :

```
lst = await context.Query<Authenticate>().FromSql(sqlQuery, usernameParam, passwordParam).ToListAsync();
```

**context** beeing a **DbContext** instance

anyone knows how to fix this ?

I have checked the microsoft doc, it says it's obsolete but does not point to it's replacement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement for `Query<T>()` is `Set<T>()`.

So following your example it'd be something like this:

```
lst = await context.Set<Authenticate>().FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery, usernameParam,passwordParam).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I get 'RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSql<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity>, RawSqlString, params object[])' is obsolete: 'For returning objects from SQL queries using plain strings, use FromSqlRaw instead. For returning objects from SQL queries using interpolated string syntax to create parameters, use FromSqlInterpolated instead. Call either new method directly on the DbSet at the root of the query.'

Comment: right, my mistake. I edited the answer so it uses `FromSqlRaw()` that is the correct one

Comment: it compiles indeed :-)

Comment: but I dont need a list to be returned, is it possible retunr only the Authenticate object ?

Comment: that's worked for me